# Postgres 9.5.2 sorting differently in development vs production

Tags: postgresql, sorting

**UPDATED**

In my rails app using postgresql, I've composed an Active Record query to find a group of volunteer records and then order them by `first_name`, then `last_name`, then `email`. Additionally, `first_name` and `last_name` may be `null` (either both will be `null` or both will be not `null`). The sql Active Record generates looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(COALESCE("volunteers"."first_name", "volunteers"."email")), LOWER(COALESCE("volunteers"."last_name", "volunteers"."email")), LOWER("volunteers"."email"), "volunteers".* 
FROM "volunteers" 
INNER JOIN "volunteer_list_connectors" ON "volunteer_list_connectors"."volunteer_id" = "volunteers"."id" 
INNER JOIN "volunteer_lists" ON "volunteer_lists"."id" = "volunteer_list_connectors"."volunteer_list_id" 
WHERE ((volunteer_lists.organizer_id = 1 AND organizer_type = 'Organization') OR (volunteer_lists.organizer_id IN (1) AND organizer_type = 'Collaborative'))  
ORDER BY 
  LOWER(COALESCE("volunteers"."first_name", "volunteers"."email")) ASC, 
  LOWER(COALESCE("volunteers"."last_name", "volunteers"."email")) ASC, 
  LOWER("volunteers"."email") ASC
```

Using Postgres' `psql` tool, I copy & pasted that sql into Postgres on my development machine and on the server. On my development machine (Mac), that sql sorts the following list thusly:

1. Volunteer [first_name: 'Alex', last_name: 'Diego', email:
   'a.diego@person.com']
2. Volunteer [first_name: `null`, last_name: `null`, email:
   'cxxr@person.com']
3. Volunteer [first_name: 'Josh', last_name: 'Broger', email:
   'broger@person.com']
4. Volunteer [first_name: 'Josh', last_name: 'Broger', email:
   'jcool@person.com']
5. Volunteer [first_name: 'Josh', last_name: 'Kenton', email:
   'aj@person.com']

In my production environment (Ubuntu), Postgres responds to that same code by sorting the list like this:

1. Volunteer [first_name: `null`, last_name: `null`, email:
   'cxxr@person.com']
2. Volunteer [first_name: 'Alex', last_name: 'Diego', email:
   'a.diego@person.com']
3. Volunteer [first_name: 'Josh', last_name: 'Broger', email:
   'broger@person.com']
4. Volunteer [first_name: 'Josh', last_name: 'Broger', email:
   'jcool@person.com']
5. Volunteer [first_name: 'Josh', last_name: 'Kenton', email:
   'aj@person.com']

The difference being that volunteers with only an email address are always sorted ahead of other volunteers. Both the production environment and development environment are running PostgreSQL 9.5.2. Both are running Rails 4.2.6.

I haven't been able to figure out why my application is behaving differently in development versus production.

Anyone have any ideas? Any help / areas to explore further are GREATLY appreciated!

**UPDATE 2**

As requested in a comment, here is my psql output from my dev machine and production machine. I altered the query slightly to make the pictures readable. In this query, I've added a `LIMIT 10` and I'm only asking for `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` rather than the whole record. You'll have to take my word that both databases include `volunteers` records with only an `email` address, as well as records with `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email`. If my production database was working as expected, its output would look like the output in the first picture.

*This screen grab shows `psql` output from my dev machine (good):*

[image: This screen grab shows <code>psql</code> output from my dev machine (good)]

*This screen grab shows `psql` output from my production machine (bad). Because this is real user data in the output, I've blurred the email addresses. But the important takeaway is that records with `first_name = null` and `last_name = null` are always sorting first even when the first letter of the email address is 'Z':*

[image: This screen grab shows <code>psql</code> output from my production machine (bad)]

*and I could be wrong, but I THINK that the production machine output should show the email address in every column, were `COALESCE()` functioning properly*

## ANSWER

Thanks to @ClémentPrévost (and @muistooshort for asking the right questions of me!) I was able to figure out the answer: The records in production I thought weren't sorting properly actually had blank strings in `first_name` and `last_name` instead of `null` values (and `COALESCE()` only filters out `null` values, not blank strings). I updated my code with `NULLIF("volunteers"."first_name", \'\')` and everything started sorting properly!

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(COALESCE(NULLIF("volunteers"."first_name", ''), "volunteers"."email")), LOWER(COALESCE(NULLIF("volunteers"."last_name", ''), "volunteers"."email")), LOWER("volunteers"."email"), "volunteers".* 
FROM "volunteers" 
INNER JOIN "volunteer_list_connectors" ON "volunteer_list_connectors"."volunteer_id" = "volunteers"."id" 
INNER JOIN "volunteer_lists" ON "volunteer_lists"."id" = "volunteer_list_connectors"."volunteer_list_id" 
WHERE ((volunteer_lists.organizer_id = 1 AND organizer_type = 'Organization') OR (volunteer_lists.organizer_id IN (1) AND organizer_type = 'Collaborative'))  
ORDER BY 
  LOWER(COALESCE(NULLIF("volunteers"."first_name", ''), "volunteers"."email")) ASC, 
  LOWER(COALESCE(NULLIF("volunteers"."last_name", ''), "volunteers"."email")) ASC, 
  LOWER("volunteers"."email") ASC
```

Comment: So your ORDER BY is `LOWER(COALESCE("volunteers"."first_name", "volunteers"."email")) ASC, LOWER(COALESCE("volunteers"."last_name", "volunteers"."email")) ASC, LOWER("volunteers"."email") ASC`, right?

Comment: Correct. And that works in development but not in production. I just tested pasting the `to_sql` into postgres using the `psql` tool and in development it sorts properly, on the server it does not. Same version of postgres (though one is installed in a Mac environment, the other in an Ubuntu environment).

Comment: Are both your dev and prod db servers using the same collation / locale ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Collation / Locale features of Postgres so that might be the problem. I'll look into that now and reply when I know more.

Comment: Check the version of your database connection gem. Make sure the one in production, matches your development machine one.

Comment: PostgreSQL will use some collation information from the underlying OS but that shouldn't sort `'c'` before `'a'`. Are you sure there's no whitespace or Unicode weirdness going on? No custom collation rules in production? Can you show us the raw `psql` output from your query in production?

Comment: @Doon, after reading about both collation & locale in the Postgres documentation, I checked and the locale of both databases is the same (`en_US.utf8`) and `LC_COLLATE` for both databases is the same (`en_US.utf-8`). I have done no customizing of the location / collation rules on either database. Postgres on my machine was installed with Homebrew and on the server with `apt-get` . Other than adding a role and a database to each instance (and of course the records), I've done no customizing of either Postgres. If you have suggestions for additional areas to check for rules I'll gratefully check

Comment: @gwnp, I've checked and both versions of the app use version `0.18.4` of the PG gem. But of course, even if they didn't, that wouldn't explain how output from PSQL's processing of the raw SQL is different on one machine vs the other.

Comment: @muistooshort, I've updated my question with screen grabs of the raw `psql` input and output. As I commented to @Doon, it appears both databases are using the same encoding. Though I'll readily admit that my ability to detect whitespace / Unicode weirdness is limited by my lack of experience with databases / postgres. Originally my production app was running postgres 9.3. Before posting this question I upgraded to 9.5.2 to make sure that wasn't the cause. Though I figure the `LOWER()` and `COALESCE()` functions are supported equally well in both versions.

Comment: My hunch is that something is going wrong with the `COALESCE()` function on the server. I could be wrong, but I imagine Postgres sorts `null` ahead of `a` when done in ascending order. It seems like `COALESCE()` is always returning `first_name` and `last_name` on the server--even when `null`-- and then sorting appropriately. Are functions installed separately in any way on Postgres? Is it possible for my server's `COALESCE()` function to be messed up? Thanks all of you for your input already!!!! This has been a very frustrating problem.

Comment: In fact, I just realized that the `psql` output from the production environment returns the first two columns as blank (`null`). It *should* show the email address of each record in every column. Much like in the `psql` output from my dev machine: when a record only has an email address that email address shows up in every column (rows 5, 7, and 8 in the dev screen grab)

Comment: Are those really nulls or simply empty strings ? You can use `\pset null ¤` to distinguish between the two.

Comment: I'm with @ClémentPrévost so far. It is highly unlikely that COALESCE is broken, it is more likely that `first_name` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @ClémentPrévost, thats EXACTLY what it was! THANK YOU!! I updated my code with NULLIF( value, '' ) and now its sorting properly. When I read your comment it made complete sense. Though it never occurred to me that blank strings wouldn't be filtered out by `COALESCE()`. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you again! And thank you @muistooshort, @Doon, and @gwnp. I really appreciate your taking the time to help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those really nulls or simply empty strings ?

You can use `\pset null ¤` to distinguish between the two.

PS: great discussion in the question comments!